# pdo. не показывает полученные данные

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем привет, пишу с такой проблемой, что не выводит полученные данные с MySQL в PHP страницу, использую библиотеку (если её так можно назвать) PDO, только начал с ним работать, ещё не всё особо понятно.

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM moders_chat ORDER BY priority;";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    list($id, $idt, $ltg, $nntg, $post, $prefix, $warns, $points, $status) = $stmt->fetch();

    echo '<tr>
    <td> <a href=../pages/user?id='.$idt.'>'.$idt.'</a></td>
    <td>'.$ltg.'</td>
    <td>'.$nntg.'</td>
    <td>'.$post.'</td>
    <td>'.$prefix.'</td>
    <td>'.$warns.'</td>
    <td>'.$points.'</td>
    <td>'.$status.'</td></tr>';
?>
```

Comment: В-первых, перед выполнением запросов надо сначала соединиться с БД. Во-вторых, при соединении надо настроить ПДО, чтобы оно сообщало об ошибках. И в третьих, надо настроить РНР, чтобы он тоже сообщал об ошибках. После этого при возникновении проблем читать сообщение об ошибке и исправлять его.

Comment: Кроме того, надо определиться, одну строку вы хотите получить, или много. Если много, то их надо выводить в цикле. Если одну, то и запрашивать надо тоже одну, а не все. Как это сделать, можно почитать, например, здесь https://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score -2):

Необходимо указать возвращение результата в виде массива:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM moders_chat ORDER BY priority;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
list($id, $idt, $ltg, $nntg, $post, $prefix, $warns, $points, $status) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Для этого используется PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Также посмотрите через var_dump(), что у вас вернулось после выполнения запроса.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM moders_chat ORDER BY priority;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Если ничего нет, нужно смотреть, какие есть ошибки при подключении к базе данных и выполнении запроса.

Comment: я так понял после $stmt->execute();?

Comment: ситуация не изменилась, можем ли мы перейти в телеграмм, для удобства? @dlebarov

Comment: Сталкивался с проблемой, что без ковычек запрос не обрабатывался, попробуй закрыть название таблицы в ковычки ` - (клавиша ё)

Comment: @Red слово "кавычка" пишется через букву "а"

Comment: К сожалению, с PDO::FETCH_ASSOC этот код как раз перестанет что-либо выводить, даже если запрос вернет какие-то данные